# How to get list with all TFS test cases, which were executed on a specific release/build with Excel Data Warehouse or query?

Tags: excel, tfs, data-warehouse, testcase, azure-analysis-services

In Microsoft TFS (Team Foundation Server), is there a way to get a list of all test cases, which were executed for a specific release or build? Possible solutions are to use a TFS query or TFS Analysis Services data cube via Excel ("Data / Get data / Analysis Service"). I use TFS 2017.

Best way until now is to go into TFS "Test Plans" section and do an export (right click on Test plan or test suite). With option "Latest test outcome" I get information, which test case was last executed on which release.

But I need vice versa: When selecting one specific release, which test cases were passed/failed, etc., including tester and DateTime.

Comment: What do you mean by "is it okay"? Of course it's okay.

Comment: What is "Excel Data Warehouse" ??

Comment: Please find my updated text.